# Create a list of vectors of consecutive values from a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector of integers with 'discountinuities' and I would like to convert in a list of vectors with consecutive values

Example

```
vec = c(1,2,5,7,8,9,11,12,13,15)
[1]  1  2  5  7  8  9 11 12 13 15
```

Expected output:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 7 8 9

[[4]]
[1] 11 12 13

[[5]]
[1] 15
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to `split` by creating a grouping variable created by checking the `diff`erence of adjacent elements

```
split(vec, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(vec) != 1)))
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2

#$`2`
#[1] 5

#$`3`
#[1] 7 8 9

#$`4`
#[1] 11 12 13

#$`5`
#[1] 15
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks ! i will accept the answer when stackoverflow will allow me to